# Unable to extract entire webpage using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract a value from a webpage.

The URL I am trying to scrape from is: 
http://www.flipkart.com/philips-qt4005-15-trimmer/p/itmdze53vthypqhb?pid=SHVDGGZPC8PXJ7HR&al=wUEQZ4vph4oJqeH0CGNkrsldugMWZuE7eGHgUTGjVrpjizeD%2FNvlpAEwWx6I1Qy9R9ViMaFmI%2Bc%3D&ref=L%3A-1246372967349401781&srno=b_1

and the value I want to extract is `Tue, 19th Apr`.

First of, I used the following code to store the source of the html page to a local file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
f = open("deldate.csv",'w')
g = open("flip.csv",'w')
request = requests.get("http://www.flipkart.com/philips-qt4001-15-trimmer-men/p/itmdu7ymtpdptghq?pid=SHVDU7YMTPDPTGHQ&al=wUEQZ4vph4o9VS1qRXcBE8ldugMWZuE7eGHgUTGjVrrcVamAbZwaUArMgFo2ArKEQzMEtMlIvg8%3D&ref=L%3A6510162326865727417&srno=p_2&query=trimmers+for+men&otracker=from-search").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(request)
g.write(str(soup))
```

Then I wrote the following code to extract the value :

```
for line in soup.findAll('div', class_="delivery-ndd-help-message fk-hidden"):
    for line1 in line.findAll('span',class_="fk-bold"):
        ddate = line2.text
        print (str(ddate))
```

But the program returned a null value. So, I opened to the file where I saved the html of the webpage and tried to search for 'Tue, 19th Apr' but was unable to find it.

I have tried using

```
import urllib2
request = urllib.open(""http://www.flipkart.com/philips-qt4001-15-trimmer-men/p/itmdu7ymtpdptghq?pid=SHVDU7YMTPDPTGHQ&al=wUEQZ4vph4o9VS1qRXcBE8ldugMWZuE7eGHgUTGjVrrcVamAbZwaUArMgFo2ArKEQzMEtMlIvg8%3D&ref=L%3A6510162326865727417&srno=p_2&query=trimmers+for+men&otracker=from-search")
```

in hopes of extracting all the content from the webpage, but even that doesn't seem to work.

Can someone please suggest if there is a better way to extract all the content from a webpage?

Comment: I open the link in my browser and I can't find `Tue, 19th Apr`

Comment: Hi @AminahNuraini, I have trouble finding it as well.. That is why I posted the question.. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.flipkart.com/philips-qt4005-15-trimmer/p/itmdze53vthypqhb?pid=SHVDGGZPC8PXJ7HR&al=wUEQZ4vph4oJqeH0CGNkrsldugMWZuE7eGHgUTGjVrpjizeD%2FNvlpAEwWx6I1Qy9R9ViMaFmI%2Bc%3D&ref=L%3A-1246372967349401781&srno=b_1"
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

This will collect the  whole webpage. Now if you want to search the paragraph tags or something, you can use this line:

```
tags=soup('p')
```

Then you can loop through the tags and search for data you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you refer to the `RECENT TOP REVIEWS` list.

The dates has a specific class `review-date`.

Try to filter on that:

`soup.findAll('p', class_="review-date")`